# echo stderr and stdout to file from bash script variable

Tags: linux, bash, stdout, stderr

I have a bash script and inside this bash script I have a JAVARESULT variable like this :

```
JAVARESULT=`java -cp ... parser_file $file $someextravar`
```

and what I want is to catch in a log file the stderr and stdout of this result variable.

```
echo "$JAVARESULT" > $LOG_FILE
```

but i get only the stdout not the stderr. I tried with :

```
echo "$JAVARESULT" &> $LOG_FILE
```

but I don't get the java errors in the log file .

Comment: `java -cp ... parser_file $file $someextravar &> $LOG_FILE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every Unix based system every process have at least three file descriptors open. As you know, file descriptors are identified by numbers. This three standard file descriptors are:

- 0 for `stdin`
- 1 for `stdout`
- 2 for `stderr`

What you want to do is redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, and then redirect `stdout` to a file. So, in your `JAVARESULT` variable you'll just have to append:

```
2>&1
```

What you're saying here is: redirect `stderr` (file descriptor 2) to `stdout` (file descriptor 1).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

echo "$JAVARESULT" > $LOG_FILE 2>&1

Comment: The problem is that `JAVARESULT` does not contain standard error in the first place. Even if it did, the parameter does not store information about what parts came from standard output and which from standard error: it's just one big string.